# Angular 6 - Validate and submit form from outside the form

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(exampleForm)">
...
</form>
```

Here I'm using **Angular 6** Reactive forms.

So my outside button is,

```
<button mat-icon-button type="submit">
      <img src="../../../../../../assets/images/icon/save-1.svg"/>
</button>
```

So I want to validate the form and submit. And if there are validation errors save button should be disabled.

Here is the onSubmit() implementation.

```
onSubmit(form : FormGroup){
this.shareObjectRequest = this.shareObjectForm.value;
if (form.value.id != null) {
  this.reportShareObjectService.put(this.reportId, this.shareObjectRequest).subscribe(
    result => {
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error Occured." + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}
else {
  this.reportShareObjectService.create(this.reportId, this.shareObjectRequest).subscribe(
    result => {
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error Occured" + JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you can run function within function: onButtonClick(){
onSubmit(event){console.log(event);}
}
// Your Button
<button mat-icon-button type="submit" (click)="onButtonClick">
      <img src="../../../../../../assets/images/icon/save-1.svg"/>
</button>

Comment: ... and what's your question?

Comment: @Dominique How do you validate the form and submit the form?

Comment: @Vinayak how do you validate the form?

Comment: In reactive form you implement the Validators.required, Validators.email etc in this format, this will help you : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation

Comment: @Vinayak I already implemented the validations. But the problem here is how to trigger validations?

Comment: there's no need to pass the form as parameter to your onSubmt function. onSubmit can access exampleForm property directly. After removing the parameter, you can call onSubmit in you buttons click handler.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I'm doing it to trigger that, form is inserting or editing?

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem. Can you add your onSubmit implementation and describe what you mean with "trigger validation" and "form is insertig or editing".

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I added the onSubmit() implementation.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen Inserting and editing means if it is a already created object and there are changes in the object I have to update the object otherwise I have to insert the object.

Answer (score 5):

This is achievable in HTML5 form.

```
<form id="myform" [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
.......
</form>

<div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  form="myform">Register</button>
</div>
```

Created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwu69r

Comment: How do you trigger that there are no validation errors. If there are validation errors submit button should be disabled? And I'm using an image inside the button.

Comment: You can use [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" properties with Reactive Form Valid. You can access Form Group Object using the Form Tag in Template file.

Comment: Its not working here because I'm using an image inside the submit button.

Comment: You can handle the mouse click using [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events':registerForm.valid ? 'none' : '' }"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have (simplified code)

```
class MyComponent {
   myForm = new FormGroup();
   doSave() {
      const form = this.myForm;
      // form.value.id
   }
}

<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="doSave()">
...
</form>
<ng-container *ngIf="myForm.valid">
  your button if valid
  <button (click)="doSave()">Save</button>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!myForm.valid">
  your button if NOT valid
</ng-container>
```

Now ...

- You can call `doSave()` everywhere in your view.
- `myForm.valid` will give you the info if your form is valid. You can use two separate sections as in my example if `[disabled]="myForm.valid"` does not work for you.

Comment: The problem here is that the `ngSubmit` event is never triggered. You are directly calling the `doSave()` method

Comment: @Niko - not really, you can submit a form by pressing enter when e.g. an input has focus, so yes, the button does not trigger submit but other form controls will do. (but we could / should simply remove the button click handler and have the same effect).

Comment: You are right. However in my opinion this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52555427/10476047) completely solves this problem (and more elegantly i would say) by simply using the native HTML5 attribute `form =" form_id "` on the `<button>` (even if the button is outside the form)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer. But button is not shaded here.For that I need to use ngStyle in the button.

```
<button form="ngForm" mat-icon-button type="submit" [disabled]="myform.invalid">
      <img  src="../../../../../../assets/images/icon/save-1.svg"/>
</button>

<form [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(shareObjectForm)" id="ngForm">
</form>

onSubmit(form : FormGroup){
   this.shareObjectRequest = this.shareObjectForm.value;
   if (form.value.id != null) {
      this.reportShareObjectService.put(this.reportId, this.shareObjectRequest).subscribe(
         result => {
      },
         err => {
           console.log("Error Occured." + JSON.stringify(err));
         });
    }
    else {
       this.reportShareObjectService.create(this.reportId, this.shareObjectRequest).subscribe(
         result => {
         },
         err => {
            console.log("Error Occured" + JSON.stringify(err));
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: Only button is not shaded here. But if there are validation errors you can't submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Create Form With or without `form` tag.

Fire validation from your `ts`.

```
submitForm() {
   for (let v in this.exampleForm.controls) {
         this.exampleForm.controls[v].markAsTouched();
   }
   if (this.exampleForm.valid) {

   }
}
```

And use `(click)` inside your html.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
 (click)="submitForm()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/email-phone-validation-reactive)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have done the FormGroup in the component and thats what you are binding to in the template you just need to reference the FormGroup again in the disabled attr.

Even when in my example the button is inside form that's irrelevant, 'cause you are using the a variable declared in the component as a reference, therefore you could use it where ever in your html

```
<form autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="actualFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" class="data-form">
  ...

  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button class="classic-purple-button cursor-pointer no-outline" [disabled]="!actualFormGroup.valid" type="submit">
        Continuar
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The title clearly says "Validate and submit form FROM OUTSIDE THE FORM"